# Ubuntu 16.04 List of Wireless not Showing Up

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

This is my Wireless info :

########## wireless info START ##########

```
Report from: 26 Apr 2018 17:25 WIB +0700

Booted last: 26 Apr 2018 00:00 WIB +0700

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.13.0-39-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 5 16:43:10 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Harrier
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:21f7]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9500 [Galaxy S4] / GT-I9250 [Galaxy Nexus] (network tethering)
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wmi_bmof               16384  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp0s16f0u1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp0s16f0u1' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.170  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::31ba:e84e:f841:69a5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10031 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9553066 (9.5 MB)  TX bytes:1674879 (1.6 MB)

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1279 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1279 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:96207 (96.2 KB)  TX bytes:96207 (96.2 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp0s16f0u1  no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s16f0u1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s16f0u1
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s16f0u1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       887     1  0 17:17 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s16f0u1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         SAMSUNG
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        SAMSUNG_Android
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s16f0u1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/net/enp0s16f0u1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s16f0u1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       9d2c5522-5e54-32b0-8c73-03c3acf2c2d0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{38}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   9d2c5522-5e54-32b0-8c73-03c3acf2c2d0 | Wired connection 2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.170/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.170
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1524741611
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = darkterminal
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::31ba:e84e:f841:69a5/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.5/0000:04:00.0/net/enp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BKgI-YW5pa2FzbWF3YXRpNTE]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BKgI-YW5pa2FzbWF3YXRpNTE | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BKgI-YW5pa2FzbWF3YXRpNTE
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ndazmu]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ndazmu | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ndazmu
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/lantai20]] (600 root)
[connection] id=lantai20 | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=lantai20
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Beta Dev Indonesia]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Beta Dev Indonesia | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Beta Dev Indonesia
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TF-WIFI_A1ECA0]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TF-WIFI_A1ECA0 | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TF-WIFI_A1ECA0
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TP KULINER 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TP KULINER 2 | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TP KULINER 2
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/@wifi.id]] (600 root)
[connection] id=@wifi.id | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=@wifi.id
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/UMMagelang]] (600 root)
[connection] id=UMMagelang | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=UMMagelang
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/zhio.hotspot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=zhio.hotspot | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=zhio.hotspot
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/blanco coffee & books]] (600 root)
[connection] id=blanco coffee & books | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=blanco coffee & books
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DESKTOP-EHCC1V8 3834]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DESKTOP-EHCC1V8 3834 | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=DESKTOP-EHCC1V8 3834
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/lantai20 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=lantai20 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=lantai20
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ora gratisan yo]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ora gratisan yo | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ora gratisan yo
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SUPERBOY]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SUPERBOY | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SUPERBOY
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BIPA OFFICE]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BIPA OFFICE | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BIPA OFFICE
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/pavilliun taruna]] (600 root)
[connection] id=pavilliun taruna | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=pavilliun taruna
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Speedy Instan@wifi.id]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Speedy Instan@wifi.id | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Speedy Instan@wifi.id
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/STMIK BIPA MAGELANG 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=STMIK BIPA MAGELANG 2 | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=STMIK BIPA MAGELANG 2
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/STMIK BINA PATRIA MAGELANG]] (600 root)
[connection] id=STMIK BINA PATRIA MAGELANG | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=STMIK BINA PATRIA MAGELANG
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/oragratisanyo]] (600 root)
[connection] id=oragratisanyo | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=oragratisanyo
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/password]] (600 root)
[connection] id=password | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=password
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BnKU-ZmFpbmFsYXppczc4Ng]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BnKU-ZmFpbmFsYXppczc4Ng | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BnKU-ZmFpbmFsYXppczc4Ng
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Luwak With Coffe]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Luwak With Coffe | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Luwak With Coffe
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/_...]] (600 root)
[connection] id=.... | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=....
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/oii]] (600 root)
[connection] id=oii | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=oii
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BAxs-a2h1c25p]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BAxs-a2h1c25p | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BAxs-a2h1c25p
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/STMIK MHS 3]] (600 root)
[connection] id=STMIK MHS 3 | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=STMIK MHS 3
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/@wifi.id 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=@wifi.id 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=@wifi.id
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Lt. 3]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Lt. 3 | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Lt. 3
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JAVNIK CAFE]] (600 root)
[connection] id=JAVNIK CAFE | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=JAVNIK CAFE
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MDF CC]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MDF CC | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MDF CC
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/bubble spot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=bubble spot | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=bubble spot
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/magelang-tamu]] (600 root)
[connection] id=magelang-tamu | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=magelang-tamu
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ratna linux]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ratna linux | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ratna linux
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/_..]] (600 root)
[connection] id=... | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=...
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=wifi | type=wifi | permissions=user:darkterminal:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=wifi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Jakarta (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp0s16f0u1  no frequency information.

enp4s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp0s16f0u1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options rtl81016e fwlps=N

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtlbtcoex.conf]
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   24.880953] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   24.880961] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   33.281802] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
[   33.557280] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link down
[   33.557388] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
[  173.243687] rndis_host 5-1:1.0 enp0s16f0u1: renamed from usb0
[  173.273112] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s16f0u1: link is not ready
[  185.028506] rndis_host 5-1:1.0 enp0s16f0u1: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:10.0-1, RNDIS device
[  185.531722] rndis_host 5-1:1.0 enp0s16f0u1: renamed from usb0
[  185.749745] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s16f0u1: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

in wireless panel on the top right list of wifi not showing.
Thanks, i hope any help

Comment: What happens if you `sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-39-generic

Answer (score 0):

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Post any errors or warnings. If none, reboot and your wireless should be working.